# How do I correctly add one model to another in Flutter?

Tags: android, django, database, flutter, django-rest-framework

I'm really confused on how do I add director model to my show model. I'm writing Android application  in Flutter, that uses local Django Rest API.

This is Director Model in Django

```
class Director(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images/")
```

This is Shows Model in Django

```
class Show(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    annotation = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images/")
    director = models.ForeignKey(Director, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

This is Director Model in Flutter

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class DirectorModel with ChangeNotifier {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  final String surname;
  final String image;

  DirectorModel({required this.id, required this.name, required this.surname, required this.image});

  factory DirectorModel.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    return DirectorModel(
      id: json['id'],
      name: json['name'] as String,
      surname: json['surname'] as String,
      image: json['image'] as String,
    );
  }

  static List<DirectorModel> directorFromSnapshot(List snapshot) {
    return snapshot.map((data) {
      return DirectorModel.fromJson(data);
    }).toList();
  }
}
```

This is Shows model in Flutter

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:kulises_app/models/directors.dart';

class ShowsModel with ChangeNotifier {
  int id;
  String name;
  String annotation;
  String language;
  DirectorModel director;
  String image;

  ShowsModel(
      {required this.id,
      required this.name,
      required this.annotation,
      required this.language,
      required this.director,
      required this.image});

  factory ShowsModel.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    return ShowsModel(
      id: json['id'],
      director: DirectorModel.fromJson(json['director']),
      name: json['name'] as String,
      annotation: json['annotation'] as String,
      language: json['language'] as String,
      image: json['image'] as String,
    );
  }

  static List<ShowsModel> showsFromSnapshot(List snapshot) {
    print(snapshot);
    return snapshot.map((data) {
      return ShowsModel.fromJson(data);
    }).toList();
  }

}
```

I'm getting this error `_TypeError (type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>')` on this line `director: DirectorModel.fromJson(json['director']),`. Such a small error but I really can't figure it out...

The idea is- I have this info page about a show, and I need to display director name and surname.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that `DirectorModel.fromJson(json['director'])` is giving an error since it expects a parameter of type `Map<String, dynamic>` but is getting an `int`. This means that `json['director']` returns an `int`.

Steps to debugging:

1. Print out all of the json.
2. Find out where the `director` entry is coming from in the first place.
3. Find out why it isn't of the form that you are expecting(int instead of Map<String, dynamic>).
4. Fix.

Update your post if you get stuck or have solved your problem.